# change image based on jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the background image of an element inside a slider div based upon the slider value. The images are in a resource folder of eclipse ...

I have a CSS class named `character` and in that class I have a `background-image` rule which I want to change when the slider value changes.

Currently when I slide a slider, all the `character` elements background images change. This is not the behavior that I desire. I want each `character` element's background image to change only when its wrapping slider changes.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".<%=i%>" ).slider({
            disabled:false,
            animate:"slow",
            range: "min",
            value:6,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#<%=i%>" ).val(  ui.value );
                $( "#hidden<%=i%>" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
        $( "#<%=i%>" ).val(  $( ".<%=i%>" ).slider( "value" ) );
        $( "#hidden<%=i%>" ).val(  $( ".<%=i%>" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
</script>
<script>
    if($( "#hidden<%=i%>" ).val( ui.value )==6)
    {       
        $('.character', this).css("background-image", "url(../images/characters/1.png)");
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: first of all image is not changing and secondly if i change image of class then image associated to every slider will change

Comment: i want to change image of only the slider whose value gets changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code to change the background is in the wrong place and syntactically incorrect.

You need to have your trigger in an event tied to an element. Right now in your script it is looking at the document when you are trying to change the background image. Therefore `this` as context is the document and all the `character` elements are going to be selected.

if you did this instead:

```
$(".<%=i%>").slider({
    disabled: false,
    animate: "slow",
    range: "min",
    value: 6,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#<%=i%>").val(ui.value);
        $("#hidden<%=i%>").val(ui.value);
    },
    change: function(event, ui){
        if(ui.value == 6){
            $('.character', this).css("background-image", "url(../images/characters/1.png)");
        }else{
            $('.character', this).css("background-image", "{some other/default image}");
        }
    }
});
```

Then the `this` context is actually the sllider div.

[Here is an example where I changed the background color instead of an image](http://jsfiddle.net/9qjZB/)

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer ...now it is detecting which slider value is changing and it is going in if part but in my code not changing color or image what could be the possible reasons?

Comment: I am only guessing at your html, but where do your `character` elements live in the DOM tree? are they contained in the slider divs? or are they outside of them?